# ElasticSearch moving nodes within a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a multiple document, that have nested objects. I need to move the location of the nested objects within the document.

How can i do this, say move users out of groups in the following example:

```
{
  "resourceGroup": "",
  "abc": "Ok",
  "firstSeen": "2020-03-16T08:45:02.444Z",
  "entityId": "29e7d555-1959-4b9b-b663-ce0d04f3e5a7",
  "type": "GroupEntity",
  "group": {
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": ,
    "mailNickname": "74b06328-1",
    "users": [
      {
        "mail": "abc@aaa.com",
        "mailNickname": "sdf"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "test user",
        "mailNickname": "testuser1"
      }
    ],

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)

> Use an ingest node to pre-process documents before the actual document indexing happens. The ingest node intercepts bulk and index requests, it applies transformations, and it then passes the documents back to the index or bulk APIs.

Sample Mapping

```
PUT index54
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "resourceGroup": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "group": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "users": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "mail": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "mailNickname": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ingest Pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/moveuserspropertypipeline
{
  "description" : "move users out of group",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "users",
        "value": "{{group.users}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "group.users"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) documents can be copied from source index to new index.
Create destination index with correct mapping before executing reindex api

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index54"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index55",
    "pipeline": "moveuserspropertypipeline"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it resole your issue?